# What names from Star Wars are often misspelled?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I've created [a query to search for commonly misspelled names from *Tolkien's Legendarium*](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13622/19561).

Since [*Millennium Falcon* seems prone to being misspelled as well](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60449123#60449123), as well as "Wookiee", we may want to have a similar query for the *Star Wars* franchise.

**What names from *Star Wars* are often misspelled?**

We could add the query to [our compendium of useful queries](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9496/19561) to keep an eye on any future misspellings.

Comment: Can you define 'often'?

Comment: @Valorum at least twice.

Comment: People often misspell Jar Jar Binks as @#%^

Comment: @Machavity is that _really_ misspelling, though?

Comment: I have seen Leia misspelled more than once.

Answer (score 9):

Candidates so far:

- Ahsoka (often misspelled "Ashoka")
- C-3PO (I've found C3-PO, C-3P0 and even C3-P0)
- [Coruscant](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13626/20774)
- Exegol
- Force with a lower-case 'f'
- Kashyyyk
- [Lightsaber](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11134/is-it-lightsabre-or-lightsaber-or-both)
- Millennium Falcon
- Tatooine (doubled "t", single "o"; it looks like I've fixed all but a few cases of "Tattoine")
- Wookiee
- Wookieepedia (single "e", no "ee", various misspellings of "pedia", "y" instead of "i"...  Most of these were fixed relatively recently)

Comment: Can you give any example of Coruscant being misspelled? Aside from your own misspelling, on this post, I mean.

Comment: @Valorum Wookiee and Wookieepedia get quite commonly corrected. That said you've misspelt both in your comment. Exegol was misspelt quite a lot when the film initially released.

Comment: @Valorum "Wookieepedia" is almost always correctly spelled **now** because I spent a month fixing hundreds of misspelled variants.

Answer (score 7):

Valorum asks for examples of **Coruscant** being misspelled.  I added that word because I know I can't spell it.  But now I searched a dump for examples.  (This is from an old dump from 2020, that's what I had already downloaded on my disk.)  Some of these have since been edited to the correct spelling, but I think they still count as evidence that the name is often misspelled.

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/188463/1 Corescant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95009 Coriscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/28344/1 Coroscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68903/ Corrasant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/197341/1 Corrusant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117390/ Corruscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/10315/2 Corscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/134384/1 Corusant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172498/ Corusant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/68480/1 Corusant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112008/ Courascant
- [How is time measured in the galaxy far far away?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123848/) Courescant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/125659/1 Coursicant, Couriscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/51456/1 Couriscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144131/ Courscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/173034/1 Courscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/178735/1 Courscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/103570/1 Crouscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/129623/1 Curoscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/228106/1 corasant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/53413/1 corruscant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/131784/1 corusant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76227/ corusant
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/117460/1 courascant

Comment: I'm guessing that I've edited it a few times :-)