# Copying answers for likely duplicates

Tags: discussion

This may be particular to `story-identification`, but, for example, I realized that [Novel where government trains kids for the army through a VR game](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186454/novel-where-government-trains-kids-for-the-army-through-a-vr-game) was likely referring to *The Roar*, which I had previously answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150995/sci-fi-book-about-a-male-entering-a-competition-that-he-wins-and-gets-recruited?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170763/story-about-boy-living-in-a-city-sheltered-from-post-nuclear-fallout?noredirect=1&lq=1). My standard story-ID answer template is the title of the story linked to Goodreads (or similar site), the author, a cover image, and a quoted summary from the link which answers the question. In this case, I didn't need to add anything new, so I copied it over.

On one hand, I'm basically duplicating information, which doesn't really help most people since it's already on the site and will be linked over once marked as a duplicate. On the other hand, it's useful to the querent to have all of that information specifically addressed to their question, and if the querent doesn't accept it (or even comment that it's the right one), we still have a direct link from the question details to the answer details.

Comment: Generally I tend to post a comment when there's an obvious dupe. If OP doesn't close the Q as a dupe within a few hours, I'll repost the answer. If they never come back, the questions will never get dupe-closed so it's still useful to have the info on the site, even if it's the same as another question

Comment: [Related question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11828/31394). But story-ID is a special case, as you say, so I don't think this meta is a dupe.

Comment: Since story-id can't be marked dupe without an accepted answer (right?) posting an identical answer *does* help. (Personally I think the best story-id answers are the ones that specifically address the things the asker remembers, which is useful to later readers who may remember only some details the original asker did, but I get that you may not want to go to all the trouble of customizing answers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What I do in this case](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146438/19561), is that I quote my original answer (done easily by editing that, then copying the source) after an introductory line or two.

But the important part is that while the [WoSFoF](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44404052#44404052) they're looking for may be the same, the question will likely not be. Different querants remember different aspects.
So after quoting my original answer, I address the points remembered by *this* querant if not already addressed by my original answer.

Comment: Agreed. My primary situation, though, has the answers nearly universally applicable when the full book summary is included, with additional details not being immediately at-hand without acquiring a copy of the book.

Comment: Although funnily enough, as I commented on one of the times I answered a question seeking *The Roar*, the questions almost always remember one sibling and not the other. :-D